# How i can add elements in ArrayList and get values while loop?

Tags: java

*I have a error message "ConcurrentModificationException" When i try to add a new element in the end of list also i want get values.

```
for(Node root:node.getChild()) 

//get values root.get...

nodC=new Node();

node.getChild().add(nodeC);
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Please search before posting.](/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+concurrentmodificationexception+add) More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @T.J. Crowder. I  solve the problem by other solution.